# com.sun.istack.internal.Nullable Annotation and Guice

Tags: java, null, guice, nullable

When Guice says that it recognizes any @Nullable annotation here (http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/UseNullable) does that mean I can use com.sun.istack.internal.Nullable provided by the Java 7 Runtime successfully?

The fact that the package name is com.sun.istack.internal leads me to believe that I probably shouldn't be using it, but it is pretty convenient to use...

Comment: I suspect that Guice is matching on simple class name, so probably yes, but still don't. You shouldn't ever use anything starting with `com.sun` with the *possible* exception of the SCTP classes. Just attach a suitable JSR-305 jar instead.

Comment: Seems like JSR-308 (https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=308) would be a better choice because JSR-305 is dormant (https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If null is permissible by your class, you can annotate the field or parameter with @Nullable. Guice recognizes any @Nullable annotation, like [edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.Nullable](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/Nullable.html) or [javax.annotation.Nullable](http://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/source/browse/trunk/ri/src/main/java/javax/annotation/Nullable.java?r=24). —from the [Guice site](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/UseNullable)

To confirm [chrylis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis)'s hunch above, Guice simply [tests the name of the class](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/Nullability.java#26).

```
// from core/src/com/google/inject/internal/Nullability.java
if ("Nullable".equals(type.getSimpleName())) {
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `Nullable` from `javax.annotation` package as the example from the site says.

If you check comments on the site, there are links to proper jar library.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

In my case I was about to use Nullable annotation from IntelliJ package. :)